# Dynamically spread text to multiple lines according to their length in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, cross-platform

So, I am building this app in flutter where users can comment in upto 150 characters and when I am trying to display it there's this render overflow error because of the length of the string. So, how can I spread the text to multiple lines based on their length and display them accordingly. There's a similar question here but that does not solve my problem. Can I get some help?

```
Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 100.0,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/c1.png',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          width: 69,
                          height: 69,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        const Text(
                          '@username',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        Expanded(child: const Text('fwegergwefrvgervuhygtfvrcdxddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddne, a very long comment!!!', 
                        textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                        maxLines: 6,
 overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `Column` with an `Expanded` widget

```
Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 100.0,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ClipOval(
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/c1.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  width: 69,
                  height: 69,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    '@username',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: const Text(
                    'fwegergwefrvgervuhygtfvrcdxddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddne, a very long comment!!!',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                    maxLines: 6,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  )),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```